# JAVA : How do I reduce the timer's time when the timer is running?

Tags: java, swing, timer

### Question

I want to make everytime i input the wrong answer the time reducing and i have more panel like this, i want to make when i move to next panel the time start, not when i compile the file the timer start the same time.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
    int time = 7000;
    ans2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                if(ans2.getText().toUpperCase().equals("CAT")){
                    word.setText("CAT");
                    ans2.setText("");
                    if(word.getText().equals("CAT") && word2.getText().equals("CARD") && word3.getText().equals("TILES") && word4.getText().equals("MIRROR") && word5.getText().equals("COUCH") && word6.getText().equals("STRAW")){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "COMPLETE\n Go to Next Stage");
                        word.setText(""); word2.setText(""); word3.setText(""); word4.setText(""); word5.setText(""); word6.setText("");
                        timer.stop();
                        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) main.getLayout();
                        cl.show(main, "Stage2");
                    }
                }
                //i want to make "else if wrong answer time reduce 2 sec"
            }
        });
    JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(JProgressBar.HORIZONTAL, 0, 70);
    progressBar.setValue(70);
    progressBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 20));
    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {    
        int counter = 70;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            counter--;
            progressBar.setValue(counter);
            if (counter<1) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Game Over!");
                timer.stop();
                CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) main.getLayout();
                cl.show(main, "Main Menu");
            } 
        }
    };
    timer = new Timer(time, listener);
    timer.start();// i have main menu and i want the timer start when i press start button in main menu
```

Comment: Please, clean your code to leave only relevant parts. And describe *particular programming problem* which you face, not your intentions.

Comment: I found all 6 words!

Comment: @SashaSalauyou done :)

Comment: @zec yes, they are listed in the code :)

Comment: I might recommend that you have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602113/listener-placement-adhering-to-the-traditional-non-mediator-mvc-pattern/31604919#31604919) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30925564/why-is-my-jlabel-not-showing-up/30926625#30926625)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks! My problem solved

Answer (score 1):

1. You should be using a `Swing Timer` not an AWT Timer. Read the API there are methods that allow you to set/change the timer delay.
2. Don't use a KeyListener to handle the Enter key on a text field. Instead you should be adding an ActionListener to the text field. The Enter key will then invoke the action.

Comment: but i use import javax.swing.Timer; is that doesnt make any difference ?

Comment: @KiraKatou, What method did you use to change the delay? Why does your code still use the KeyListener?

Comment: about the method i still noob at timer dude, i already change that to actionlistener

Comment: @KiraKatou, ` i still noob at timer`  - and that is why you need to read the API and try the methods you find in the API.

Comment: i already read dude, i think that i only need actionlistener, start and stop method and i have try restart method and no changes. instead delay is used to slow down time?