# Using CardLayout for multiple JPanels and nothing displays

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, cardlayout

I'm making a simple (and bogus) computer power consumption calculator. I'm using a card layout to put multiple panels in but when I run it, there's just a small window not displaying anything. Here's my long code, I put it all in one class.

```
package my.Project;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.*;


public class MainProject extends JFrame {

CardLayout cl;

int motherboardP, oddP, hddP, ssdP, fanP, cpuP, gpuP, monitorP, hoursint;
int ramNum, hddNum, ssdNum, fanNum, gpuNum;
double ramP, totalP, powerPerYear;
public float tariff = (float) 0.2180;
public float costRM;

JPanel mainPage, secondPage, thirdPage, results;
//JPanel panelCont;
JLabel title, icon, motherboard, ram, numram,
        numssd, numhdd, odd, numfan, cpu, gpu,
        numgpu, monitor, hours, outage, peryear,
        costyear, watt, kwatt, rm;

JButton start, exit1, exit2, nxt1, bck1, nxt2, bck2, done, bck3, tips, calc;

JTextField numRam, numSSD, numHDD, numFan, numGpu, hoursUse,
        outagePC, perYear, cost;

JComboBox mboardBox, ramBox, oddBox, cpuBox, gpuBox,
        monitorBox;

public MainProject() {
    initComponents();
}

public void initComponents() {

    setTitle("Power Consumption Calculator");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(500, 400);

    Container contentPane = getContentPane();

    contentPane.setLayout(cl);

    /*
    panelCont = new JPanel();
    cl = new CardLayout();
    */

    //contentPane.add(panelCont);

    /*
    panelCont.setLayout(cl);
    panelCont.add(mainPage,"1");
    panelCont.add(secondPage,"2");
    panelCont.add(thirdPage,"3");
    panelCont.add(results,"4");
    cl.show(panelCont,"1");
    */

    mainPage = new JPanel();

    secondPage = new JPanel();

    thirdPage = new JPanel();

    results = new JPanel();

    cl.show(contentPane,"1");

    contentPane.add("1", mainPage);
    contentPane.add("2", secondPage);
    contentPane.add("3", thirdPage);
    contentPane.add("4", results);

    title.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 18));
    title.setText("Computer Power Consumption Calculator");
    motherboard.setText("Motherboard:");
    ram.setText("RAM:");
    numram.setText("No. of RAM Sticks:");
    numssd.setText("Num. of SSD:");
    numhdd.setText("Num. of HDD:");
    odd.setText("Optical Disk Drive:");
    numfan.setText("Num. of Fans:");
    cpu.setText("CPU:");
    gpu.setText("GPU:");
    numgpu.setText("Num. of GPU:");
    monitor.setText("Monitor:");
    hours.setText("Hours of usage/day:");
    outage.setText("PC Power Outage:");
    peryear.setText("Per year:");
    costyear.setText("Cost/year");
    watt.setText("Watts (W)");
    kwatt.setText("kiloWatts(kW)");
    rm.setText("RM");

    icon.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/my/Project/pclogo.png")));

    BorderLayout mainL = new BorderLayout();
    mainPage.setLayout(mainL);
    mainPage.add(title, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    mainPage.add(icon, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainPage.add(start, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    mainPage.add(exit1,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    GridLayout secondL = new GridLayout(0,2);
    secondPage.setLayout(secondL);
    secondPage.add(motherboard);
    secondPage.add(mboardBox);
    secondPage.add(ram);
    secondPage.add(ramBox);
    secondPage.add(numram);
    secondPage.add(numRam);
    secondPage.add(numssd);
    secondPage.add(numSSD);
    secondPage.add(numhdd);
    secondPage.add(numHDD);
    secondPage.add(odd);
    secondPage.add(oddBox);
    secondPage.add(numfan);
    secondPage.add(numFan);
    secondPage.add(nxt1);
    secondPage.add(bck1);

    GridLayout thirdL = new GridLayout(0,2);
    thirdPage.setLayout(thirdL);
    thirdPage.add(cpu);
    thirdPage.add(cpuBox);
    thirdPage.add(gpu);
    thirdPage.add(gpuBox);
    thirdPage.add(numGpu);
    thirdPage.add(monitor);
    thirdPage.add(monitorBox);
    thirdPage.add(hours);
    thirdPage.add(hoursUse);
    thirdPage.add(nxt2);
    thirdPage.add(bck2);

    GridLayout resultL = new GridLayout(0,3);
    results.setLayout(resultL);
    results.add(outage);
    results.add(outagePC);
    results.add(watt);
    results.add(peryear);
    results.add(perYear);
    results.add(kwatt);
    results.add(costyear);
    results.add(cost);
    results.add(rm);
    results.add(calc);
    results.add(bck3);
    results.add(exit2);
    results.add(tips);

    start.setText("Start");
    start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            //startActionPerformed(evt);
            cl.show(contentPane,"2");
        }
    });

    exit1.setText("Exit");
    exit1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           // exit1ActionPerformed(evt);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    exit2.setText("Exit");
    exit2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           // exit2ActionPerformed(evt);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    nxt1.setText("Next >>");
    nxt1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          //  nxt1ActionPerformed(evt);
            cl.show(contentPane,"3");
            ramNum = Integer.parseInt(numRam.getText());
            ssdNum = Integer.parseInt(numSSD.getText());
            hddNum = Integer.parseInt(numHDD.getText());
            fanNum = Integer.parseInt(numFan.getText());

            JComboBox cb1 = (JComboBox)evt.getSource();
            String mboard = (String)cb1.getSelectedItem();
            if("Average".equals(mboard)) {
              motherboardP = 32;
            }
            if("High End".equals(mboard)) {
              motherboardP = 60;
            }

            JComboBox cb2 = (JComboBox)evt.getSource();
            String ramType = (String)cb2.getSelectedItem();
            if("DDDR1".equals(ramType)) {
                ramP = 5;
            }
            if("DDR2".equals(ramType)) {
                ramP = 4;
            }
            if("DDR3".equals(ramType)) {
                ramP = 2.5;
            }

            JComboBox cb3 = (JComboBox)evt.getSource();
            String typeODD = (String)cb3.getSelectedItem();
            if("DVD".equals(typeODD)) {
                oddP = 22;
            }
            if("BluRay".equals(typeODD)) {
                oddP = 27;
            }


        }
    });

    nxt2.setText("Next >>");
    nxt2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           // nxt2ActionPerformed(evt);
            cl.show(contentPane,"4");

            gpuNum = Integer.parseInt(numGpu.getText());
            hoursint = Integer.parseInt(hoursUse.getText());

            JComboBox cb4 = (JComboBox)evt.getSource();
            int inCPU = (Integer)cb4.getSelectedIndex();
            switch(inCPU) {
                case 0:
                    cpuP = 89;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    cpuP = 119;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cpuP = 127;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cpuP = 125;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    cpuP = 33;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    cpuP = 98;
                    break;

            }

            JComboBox cb5 = (JComboBox)evt.getSource();
            int nvGPU = (Integer)cb5.getSelectedIndex();

            switch(nvGPU) {
                case 0:
                    gpuP = 295;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    gpuP = 100;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    gpuP = 250;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    gpuP = 150;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    gpuP = 105;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    gpuP = 275;
                    break;
            }

            JComboBox cb6 = (JComboBox)evt.getSource();
            int mSize = (Integer)cb6.getSelectedIndex();
            if(mSize == 0) {
                monitorP = 20;
            }
            if(mSize == 1) {
                monitorP = 28;
            }
            if(mSize == 2) {
                monitorP = 50;
            }

        }
    });

    bck1.setText("<< Back");
    bck1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           // bck1ActionPerformed(evt);
            cl.show(contentPane,"1");
        }
    });

    bck2.setText("<< Back");
    bck2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
          //  bck2ActionPerformed(evt);
            cl.show(contentPane,"2");
        }
    });

    bck3.setText("<< Back");
    bck3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           // bck3ActionPerformed(evt);
            cl.show(contentPane,"3");
        }
    });

    tips.setText("Tips on saving energy");
    tips.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            //tipsActionPerformed(evt);
            try {

        String url ="http://www.toptenreviews.com/computers/articles/10-computer-energy-saving-tips-go-green/";

        Desktop dt = Desktop.getDesktop();
        URI uri = new URI(url);
        dt.browse(uri.resolve(uri));
    }    

    catch (URISyntaxException | IOException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
    }
        }
    });

    calc.setText("Calculate");
    calc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           // calcActionPerformed(evt);

            gpuP *= gpuNum;
            ramP *= ramNum;
            hddP = hddNum * 5;
            ssdP = ssdNum * 3;
            fanP = fanNum * 4;

            totalP = motherboardP + cpuP + gpuP + ramP +
            hddP + ssdP + monitorP + fanP;
            powerPerYear = totalP * hoursint * 365;

            costRM = (float) ((powerPerYear / 1000) * tariff);

            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            df.format(costRM);

            String outage = Double.toString(totalP);
            String ppy = Double.toString(powerPerYear);
            String price = Float.toString(costRM);

            outagePC.setText(outage);
            perYear.setText(ppy);
            cost.setText(price);
        }
    });

    mboardBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Average", "High End" }));
    mboardBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
           // mboardBoxActionPerformed(evt);
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)evt.getSource();
            String mboard = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
            if("Average".equals(mboard)) {
              motherboardP = 32;
            }
            if("High End".equals(mboard)) {
              motherboardP = 60;
            }
        }
    });

    ramBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "DDR1", "DDR2", "DDR3" }));
    ramBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            //ramBoxActionPerformed(evt);
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)evt.getSource();
            String ramType = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
            if("DDDR1".equals(ramType)) {
                ramP = 5;
            }
            if("DDR2".equals(ramType)) {
                ramP = 4;
            }
            if("DDR3".equals(ramType)) {
                ramP = 2.5;
            }
        }
    });

    oddBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "DVD", "BluRay" }));
    oddBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            //oddBoxActionPerformed(evt);
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)evt.getSource();
            String typeODD = (String)cb.getSelectedItem();
            if("DVD".equals(typeODD)) {
                oddP = 22;
            }
            if("BluRay".equals(typeODD)) {
                oddP = 27;
            }
        }
    });

    cpuBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "intel Core i3", "intel Core i5", "intel Core i7", "AMD FX 4350", "AMD Sempron 64 3500", "AMD Athlon 64 FX-62" }));
    cpuBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            //cpuBoxActionPerformed(evt);
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)evt.getSource();
            int inCPU = (Integer)cb.getSelectedIndex();
            switch(inCPU) {
                case 0:
                    cpuP = 89;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    cpuP = 119;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    cpuP = 127;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    cpuP = 125;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    cpuP = 33;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    cpuP = 98;
                    break;

            }

        }
    });

    gpuBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "NVidia GTX 500", "NVidia GTX 700", "NVidia GTX Titan", "AMD Radeon HD 2900", "AMD Radeon HD 3870", "AMD Radeon R9 Fury X" }));
    gpuBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            //gpuBoxActionPerformed(evt);
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)evt.getSource();
            int nvGPU = (Integer)cb.getSelectedIndex();

            switch(nvGPU) {
                case 0:
                    gpuP = 295;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    gpuP = 100;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    gpuP = 250;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    gpuP = 150;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    gpuP = 105;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    gpuP = 275;
                    break;
            }
        }

    });

    monitorBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "17\"-19\"", "20\"-22\"", "24\"-30\"" }));
    monitorBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            //monitorBoxActionPerformed(evt);
            JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)evt.getSource();
            int mSize = (Integer)cb.getSelectedIndex();
            if(mSize == 0) {
                monitorP = 20;
            }
            if(mSize == 1) {
                monitorP = 28;
            }
            if(mSize == 2) {
                monitorP = 50;
            }
        }

    });


}

public static void go() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    MainProject.go();

}

}
```

Where do I fix the code and how many bad Java programming practices have I implemented in my code?

Comment: Questions about bad practices go on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Based on everything I can see `cl` is `null` and it should be throwing a `NullPointerException` if you tried to run this code

Comment: You also might like to have a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) and [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer to fix this I should add cl = new CardLayout(); right? JFrame is still empty. Or should I add parameters to CardLayout() ?

Comment: `Here's my long code,` - why would you write hundreds of lines of code to test a new concept? Create a simple demo program to test the concept. Once you get the demo working you compare your working code with the code that doesn't work and fix the problem. The Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) also has working examples. `contentPane.add("4", results);` - that method is "obsolete". Read the API for the appropriate method to use.

Comment: @camickr I thought I had the right idea about the topics and decided to try patching up everything I learned so far into one small program.

Comment: @camickr according to the API, I should change to contentPane.add(jpanel, constraint) right? What do I put as constraints?

Comment: `far into one small program` - exactly so then start over with a smaller program and understand how to do it properly. That is learn to do basic debugging on your own. Don't expect us to read 100 of lines of code. `What do I put as constraints?` - It depends on the layout manager. Did you read the tutorial in using a CardLayout?. It has a working example. That is the reason I gave you the tutorial link. There is no shortcut to learning new classes and API's.

Comment: @Natecat broken code doesn't go on Code Review, and neither does hypothetical questions about best practices.

Answer (score 1):

## First...

You need to create an instance of `CardLayout` BEFORE you apply it to the container and before add any components...

```
    cl = new CardLayout();
    contentPane.setLayout(cl);
```

## Second...

You should be using the [`add(Component, Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object)) method

```
contentPane.add(mainPage, "1");
```

## Third

```
public static void go() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Does nothing but creates an empty frame with nothing in it.  It might be helpful to actually use `MainProject`, since it extends from `JFrame`

## Fourth...

Don't extend directly from `JFrame`, you're not adding any new functionality to the class, it locks you into single use cases and it cause problems like the one you're having.

Instead, consider starting with a `JPanel` instead...

```
public class MainProject extends JPanel {
```

*(ps- This change may cause other compiler errors, which I'm not going to try and fix here)*

Then simple create a new instance of a `JFrame` and add your component to it...

```
public static void go() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new MainProject());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

## Fifth

You might want to take a closer look at...

- [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

And...

- [Why is my JLabel not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30925564/why-is-my-jlabel-not-showing-up/30926625#30926625)
- [Listener Placement Adhering to the Traditional (non-mediator) MVC Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31602113/listener-placement-adhering-to-the-traditional-non-mediator-mvc-pattern/31604919#31604919)

for some more ideas and how you might better manage the `CardLayout`

You might also like to have a look at [How to Use Tabbed Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) for an alternative

Comment: Or you could just read the `How to Use CardLayout` tutorial, download the code and test it. Then if there is something you don't understand you can ask a specific question about the tutorial. People should not have to spend time paraphrasing the tutorial. So much for me trying to get you to do that first.